# Javascript xmlHTTP include form does not work in JS

Tags: php, javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

So I have an assesment page that is loaded via a post xmlHTTP and is inserted into my content ID div

```
function aload(){
    a.open("POST","http://crm/247QC/index.php",false);
            a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            a.send("java_task=assesment");  
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=a.responseText;
            setTimeout(function(){
                loadQC();
                loadplayer(document.getElementById("leadnumber").innerHTML);
            }, 3000);


        function loadQC(){
            document.getElementById("bts").innerHTML='<button id="qcSub" onClick="qcSubmit()">Submit QC Form</button>';
        }
```

The issue I am facing is because the page is a full of select dropdowns and inputs when I hit the submit button which then send it to

```
function qcSubmit(){


    var agent = document.getElementById('agent').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var p = document.getElementById('p').value;
    var one = document.getElementById('one').value;
    var two = document.getElementById('two').value;
    var three = document.getElementById('three').value;
    var four = document.getElementById('four').value;
    var five = document.getElementById('five').value;
    var six = document.getElementById('six').value;
    var seven = document.getElementById('seven').value;
    var eight = document.getElementById('eight').value;
    var nine = document.getElementById('nine').value;
    var ten = document.getElementById('ten').value;
    var eleven = document.getElementById('eleven').value;
    var twelve = document.getElementById('twelve').value;
    var thirdteen = document.getElementById('thirdteen').value;
    var fourteen = document.getElementById('fourteen').value;
    var fifthteen = document.getElementById('fifthteen').value;
    var sixteen = document.getElementById('sixteen').value;
    var seventeen = document.getElementById('aeventeen').value;
    var eighteen = document.getElementById('eighteen').value;
    var nineteen = document.getElementById('nineteen').value;
    var twenty = document.getElementById('twenty').value;
    var note = document.getElementById('comments').value;


    //alert("Yes I Ran");
    alert(note);
    p = 0;
}
```

it does not seem to be grabbing any of the div inputs or select drop downs. I am wondering why this would be. Is there a limitation that javascript cant see what xmlHTTP sends to a div because the Javascript file was loaded before the function was ran. If this is the case I need away to fix it so that the above function can see and act as it is meant to.

Comment: How far does it get, does `qcSubmit()` actually get called or not?

Comment: I don't know how I can find that out

Comment: I got this in consol when I clicked the submit button
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null core_js.js:134
qcSubmit core_js.js:134
onclick

but it did give me the alert box

Comment: Double check if you have got all the element ids correct. You are getting this error because you're trying to read the value of an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: It means whichever element is on line 134 doesn't exist for the ID you tried to target.

Comment: Check what's on the line 134 in core_js.js and verify if the id you have passed is correct.